# How to insulate underneath my bathroom vanity?

Tags: bathroom, insulation, vanity

I just moved to this house recently and notice the bathroom on the second floor is the coldest room in the house. Today, I just found out the reason. The cabinet toe kick (I think that’s how it’s called) is missing and my insulation material has been exposed.

I can’t find any instructions to fix it online so I want to ask for your help. What materials do I need to insulate the bathroom better?

[image]

Comment: You need to get behind that; see why the flooring is curling up & the insulation is spilling. New kick-board would just hide it, not fix it.

Comment: Since this is the 2nd floor, there really isn't any need to insulate the _floor_ unless it's overhanging and the under side of this floor is an exterior surface. If any of the walls are exterior walls, _they_ are what need to be insulated. Please [edit] to clarify which, if any, surfaces are exposed to the exterior of the house. You might need to remove the vanity and open up walls to get insulation in there. A hassle, to be sure, but worth it in the long run.

Comment: Insulation in the floor only helps reduce noise transmission to the room below. Oh, it could be that this bathroom is over an uninsulated garage, in which case it's probably easier to insulate from the garage side than the bathroom.

Comment: Looks like that insulation is a band aid hiding something.   Remove it, take more photos.

Comment: Exposure of wall insulation, and lack of insulation under the vanity, are not the reasons this room is cold. What and where is the source of heat for the room? How much exterior wall exposure does it have?